# How do I set up my Ubuntu Server to let my Mac connect with FTP?

Tags: 10.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 10.04, and I installed vsftpd on it. Now, I am able to connect to it with only one program which is for windows only (bleh) The program is WinSCP.

I cannot connect to the server with any other application, such as the Ubuntu connect to server, Mac connect to server, FileZilla, Web Browser, or anything that is not WinSCP.

I need to be able to connect with other applications because I mainly use a Mac to manage the server. I don't want to install wine on my Mac.

Comment: What do your logs say on the server when you are trying to connect?

Comment: When I try to connect, it says "Critical Transfer Error" whenever I try to transfer files to/from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use SFTP on your Mac to connect.

> sftp username@host_server

The commands to use SFTP on the Mac are:

```
pwd
Print working directory of remote host

lpwdPrint working directory of local client

cd
Change directory on the remote host

lcd
Change directory on the local client

ls
List director on the remote host

lls
List directory on the local client

mkdir
Make directory on remote host

lmkdir
Make directory on local client

get
Receive file from remote host to local client

put
Send file from local client to remote host

help
Display help text
```

Comment: Thank you. sftp worked perfectly for connecting and transferring files, and not very difficult to use either.